# lowest energy conformation of butan-2,4-diol

Tags: stereochemistry, alcohols, stability, conformers, stereoelectronics

Do the OH groups want to be furthest apart? or the CH3 groups?

I'm trying to determine the lowest energy conformation - and I don't know which group has the bigger steric effect?

Comment: Consider H-bonding.

Answer (score 1):

I presume it is in the gauche form that its energy is minimun because of possible hydrogen bonding between the hydroxy groups

Answer (score 0):

In butan-2-ol you have one alcohol, which is indeed smaller than the methyl group.

Comment: sorry i've just realised that I meant a diol.